# why this code doesn't work ? It involves use of pointers and functions in c

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * prime(int N);

int main()
{

    char* p = prime(13);
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}

char * prime(int N)
{
    int i,j=1;
    char yes[] = "Number is a prime";
    char no[] = "Number is not a prime";

    for(i=2; i<=N-1; i++)
    {
        if(N%i == 0)
            j=0;
    }

    if(j == 1)
        return yes ;
    else
        return no ;
}
```

Expected output =

`Number is a prime`

Shown output =

`$0@`

Comment: You must not return local pointer/array values in C. Those variables go out of scope when the function exits and the memory it points to is no longer valid.

Comment: Replace `yes[]` with `*yes`, and `no[]` with `*no`, and your code will work fine. The other solution would be to get rid of the `yes` and `no` variables, and return the strings, e.g. `return "Number is a prime";`

Comment: @user3386109 How to return  a string ? and how does the first method worked? How can we provide string to a pointer variable?

Comment: I know why we can provide string to a pointer variable , ignore that question .

Comment: Always compile your C code with (extra) warnings enabled. If you use GCC with the option `-Wall` the compiler should give you a warning about returning the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

You're reading back data using a pointer which points to memory that you don't own; the behaviour on doing this is *undefined*.

`yes` and `no` are only defined in the function `prime`.

Once that function exits, the pointer is *dangling*.

Consider writing `const char* yes = "Number is a prime";` etc. at global scope, change `prime` to return an `int` where 1 denotes primality and 0 doesn't, and use that return value in `main` to output the relevant string. Not only will this fix your bug but it's a nice design since `prime` should not really care *how* it's output value is consumed: that's the job of another function that's concerned with presenting the result. Your test for primality can also be optimised: in particular, you only need to go up to the square root of `N`.

Note how I've used `const char*` to indicate that the data are held in *read-only* memory.

Comment: If we can give an address to a function as an argument , then why can't we return an address from a function ? Isn't both the process reverse of each other?

Comment: You can return an address from a function - you just can't sensibly return the address of a local variable which will cease to exist once your function returns.